# Excel Scatter Plot Range

Tags: excel, range, scatter-plot

I'm attempting to create a scatter plot that has specific dates as the X-axis and specific times as the Y-axis. After some fidgeting around, I've gotten the desired data points but one problem remains: the range of both axises is too large.

For example, my time data points are between 6:00AM and 12:00PM but 12:00AM to 6:00AM is included and I can't get rid of it. Same goes for the dates, where the range is between 12/27/2013 and 4/30/2014, but I have dates as early as 11/22/2013 and as late as 5/21/2014.

Does anyone know how to trim this data range?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the axis in your diagram, choose "format axis". There you'll be able to  enter whatever axis range you desire (choose "fixed" instead of auto through the radio button).